# node - fs.readdir not working in files with special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having troubles with `fs.readdir` function when I want to get the files of a directory. I have used different encodings to avoid it but I can't solve it.

For instance, I have used this directory to try it.

[image]

Look at the last file, it has a special character and `fs.readdir` returns `12 - Un pa├¡s con el nombre de un r├¡o.mp3`

I just use this code to read the directory:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import {promisify} from 'util';

const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

const {err, names} = await readdir('path/to/dir');
```

Node version: `node8-alpine`

Is there a way to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, could you add the code used and the node version you are using? I just tested on node 8.5 on a mac and it's working as expected

Comment: This might be your terminal or how you're displaying it, it's returning fine for me https://i.imgur.com/NWhoaW7.png https://i.imgur.com/9xmDnee.png

Comment: @Hammerbot Yes, I added this information to the question.

Comment: And is the wrong encoding you see displayed in the regular Mac terminal? Do you use a regular font into your terminal?

Comment: @Hammerbot yes, I have used the regular Mac terminal, I think the problem isn't my terminal because I have to compare string and the validation doesn't work either

Comment: @Hammerbot How are you printing the output? I don't see that in the code

Comment: @pfg I just did a `console.log`

Comment: Possibly related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them/10484#10484

Comment: You said your Node version is `node8-alpine` — does that mean you're running in Docker and using volumes to read files on your Mac disk?